# Can't do a regex on the name of a control

Tags: c#, regex

I have some picturebox controls on a form. I need to iterate them and extract the integer in the pictureBox name. I have the following coe that works using text but does not when using the name from the control.

Works:

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"[0-9]?[0-9].");
    for (int i = 0; i < pbControls.Count; i++)
    {
        Match m = rx.Match("pictureBox8");
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
```

Does not match:

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"[0-9]?[0-9].");
    for (int i = 0; i < pbControls.Count; i++)
    {
        Match m = rx.Match(pbControls[i].Name, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
```

I even tried placing the pictureBox name in a string. The string writes to Console but I still do not get a match.

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"[0-9]?[0-9].");
    for (int i = 0; i < pbControls.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = pbControls[i].Name;
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Match m = rx.Match(s);
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
```

What am I not understanding about control names and regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "Works" in the first example? I get `m.Captures.Count = 0` with that code. Perhaps you need to remove the `'.'` character from the end?

Comment: I mean that I get a match if a use rx.Match("pictureBox8") but get no match when I use rx.Match(pcControls[i].Name) when the name is "pictureBox8".

Comment: There is no character after the digit in `"pictureBox8"`, so I don't see how you can get a match. For example, try: `int matchCount = new Regex(@"[0-9]?[0-9].").Match("pictureBox8").Captures.Count;`.  The result is `0`. Removing the `'.'` character does return the `8` as a result, however.

Comment: To be clear with your Regex you want to match one or two digits followed by any character at all (but there must be one). In short "01x" is good, "1x" is good, but "01" is bad and "1" is bad? I am wondering if you are not looking for numbers at the end (which would be "[0-9]{1,2}$" or "\d{1,2}$".

Comment: Clearly, I did not test that regex carefully enough. The dot at the end does in fact cause issues. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"pictureBox(?<num>\d+)");
    foreach (var ctrl in Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is PictureBox pb)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(pb.Name))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(pb.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It writes out the names of my "pictureBox1" and "pictureBox2" controls, but not the "pictureBoxNoNumber" control.  You can get the number out of the regex match by using the name "num" (though my code doesn't bother).

Comment: Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["num"]); ... you learn something new every day! Thank you much!